# How to enforce a type for multiple arguments in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I wrote a function that interpolates between two values. It gets the initial value, the end value, and the state. For example, from 0 to 1, state: 0.7 will be 0.7 as 0.3 * 0 + 0.7 * 1 = 0.7.

I also want it to support not just numbers but objects. For example, to interpolate from `{x: 100, y: 100}` to `{x: 500, y: 500}`, or even with deep objects: `{scale: 0, position: {x: 100, y: 100}}` to `{scale: 1, position: {x: 500, y: 500}`.

The function itself is simple, but I'm struggling with the types. I want 3 things enforced by Typescript:

1. The from and the to arguments must be numbers or objects with numbers (deep)
2. The two arguments must have the same structure. For example, if the first one is `{a: 0}` then the other one must be `{a: <number>}`
3. If the two arguments (or the latter one) are not provided, they default to 0 and 1, respectively.

Point 1) seems to be working with a recent Typescript version:

```
type NumericObject = number | {[k in string]: number | NumericObject};
```

But I don't know how to type the interpolate function. The closest I could do with my expectations is this:

```
const interpolate = <T extends NumericObject> (from: T, to : T) => (state: number):T => {
```

It types the return parameter to the union of the two arguments, which is not exactly what I need. This allows two objects with different structures, like this:

```
interpolate({a: 1}, {b: 1})(1)
```

It should throw a compile-time error saying that the two objects have different keys. Obviously, it should support any object structure, but both arguments must have the same.

And when I use default arguments, the compiler is throwing an error:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'NumericObject'.
```

Here's the code in the TS playground: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwgJwJYGMDyAjAVhdYKAXigDtFsUoAfKAbwG0BrKVMqAZ2DTIHMAugC5ylanXhI0WPAWABfANwAoZegD2ZbmzLAUYdQBsAhnpJQAPABUoEAB56yAE06xEKDDnyEAfFAAUAGbI6ggiVgA0UMDqUOEAlCR+-tymECIUCFTI8UI2xH70ylBQGlpE7HrIBiZ6AGrGhnDQpP4AbgCMIpIeMt7AUW0ATN3u0l5yUZwZYjlCPeOyhEkMxSVsgQGgkOqbnSTEpABEmdlHiUXr68gQwHDIHPsAVAEdUAC0XIkA1AHDUMZXKcUIkXpwVFd5BBDJxoJcrlAbncHlAJoQAHTBUIAUV0aAgnH8aOA6OYEBAhM68XRCGMYH8-mYiQKUBYUUq+iMaQaTQg7Q6LAEUXaQwBrmMZBA8UFU3iAni8Qh63kaxVJSR9w4HOqXPqjWaQRCCCiMSmwDSiUBUCsKhVak0nCMEHRhnUfH8a21NTS-gADFEOvE-eiAMyJAD04agvtDykVqjKjsMztd7s9uk5tT59GMIl98iiOZEHXkQZjABYI1Gi9H0eWVfH7VonS63R6Sl7ddnOOhGulo1EDJxUMBUJoRPQ7MXff6oCBp-mCwwe33i4P1MPR+OGFOoABWGdRef7mfyUvBvdV5e95N59F79ebsdkCe7kOHucid+LuMqZSRzgAAt1DgQwnFsMhAnUZB0GgYBAOgThjCQLgeDgQh7mgKDkCgbB1HggFkD4dxdE4ZROyzfwaxLQtsGLc9A0UIA)

I feel that this should be possible in Typescript but I don't see how it can be done. Is there a way to properly type this function?

Comment: The last example (line 27) should be a compiler error

Comment: I understand, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/OwE1yw) work for you?  If so I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz, this seems really good! Do you see a way to also support optional arguments?

Comment: @TamásSallai what do you mean with optional arguments? [This](https://tsplay.dev/GmZLow)?

Comment: @jcalz, I mean that the argument is missing from the call, like: interpolate()(0.5) equals interpolate(0,1)(0.5). ~60% of the time I want to interpolate between 0 and 1, so a shortcut is beneficial, if it is possible

Comment: It is possible, sure. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your requirements

- that `from` and `to` are `NumericObject`s where `to` has the same (possibly nested) keys as `from`, and so does the return type; and
- that one should be allowed to leave out `from` and `to` and they will be treated as `0` and `1`, respectively,

my inclination would be to give `interpolate` an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) function type with two call signatures:

```
interface Interpolate {
  (): (state: number) => number;
  <T extends NumericObject>(from: T, to: ToNumObj<T>): (state: number) => ToNumObj<T>;
}
type ToNumObj<T> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: ToNumObj<T[K]> } : number;
```

The first call signature will handle the case where you call `interpolate()` with no arguments.  It should eventually return a `number`.

The second call signature handles the general case.  Here, we are still giving `from` the generic type `T extends NumericObject` as you did, but for the `to` type and for the return type, we are specifically *transforming* the type of `from` (`T`) to be  something with the same structure but whose non-object properties are widened to `number` (`ToNumObj<T>`). This transformation serves several purposes:

- It gives the `T` in the type of `to` a *lower inference priority* than the `T` in the type of `from`.  So instead of the compiler seeing both `to` and `from` as being on equal footing and *possibly* synthesizing a union that you don't want, it will tend to infer `T` from `from` alone, and only *check* that `T` against `to`.  So if `to` has a property not found in `from`, you should expect to see an error instead of a union.
- Returning `ToNumObj<T>` prevents weirdness where `T`'s numeric properties or subproperties are inferred as being of [numeric literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#numeric-literal-types).  If you call `interpolate(0, 1)`, and `T` is inferred as `0`, or `0 | 1`, you certainly do not want the compiler to say that it will eventually *return* `0`, or `0 | 1`, because it probably won't.  It's fine if `T` has numeric literals in it, but we need to widen them for the return type.

---

The implementation is pretty much the same as yours except I added the `0` and `1` default values and threw a bunch of [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) in there.  There's no way the compiler can actually verify that the implementation conforms to the `Interpolate` type, so it's pretty pointless to try.  By saying that `from`, `to`, and the return type are all `any` in the implementation, I'm telling the compiler to just let me implement the function as I see fit.  Of course this makes it *my* problem (or yours, if you use this) if my implementation actually fails to do what `Interpolate` says it does, so proceed with caution:

```
const interpolate: Interpolate = (from: any = 0, to: any = 1) => (state: number): any => {
  const interpolateValue = (v1: NumericObject, v2: NumericObject, s: number): NumericObject => {
    if (typeof v1 === "number") {
      return v1 * (1 - s) + (v2 as number) * s;
    } else {
      return Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(v1).map((k) => [k, interpolateValue(v1[k], (v2 as any)[k], s)]));
    }
  }
  return interpolateValue(from, to, state);
}
```

---

Let's check out the examples:

```
console.log(
  interpolate(0, 1)(0.3).toFixed(2) // "0.30"
);

console.log(
  interpolate({ a: 0 }, { a: 1 })(0.4).a // 0.4
);

console.log(
  interpolate(
    { scale: 0, position: { x: 100, y: 100 } },
    { scale: 1, position: { x: 500, y: 500 } })
    (0.5).position.y // 300
);

console.log(
  interpolate()(0.3).toFixed(2) // "0.30"
)

interpolate({ a: 1 }, { b: 1 })(1); // error!
// -------------------> ~~~~
// Argument of type '{ b: number; }' is not assignable 
// to parameter of type '{ a: number; }'.
```

It all looks good to me. The valid calls are seen as valid, and the return types of the calls are properly typed.  The invalid call is seen as invalid, with an error telling you exactly what's wrong.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwgJwJYGMDyAjAVhdYKAXigDtFsUoAfKAbygG0BrKVMqAZ2DTIHMAugC5ylanXhI0WPASIBfANwAoUJCgAVAPZScuADyaAfCS1QIAD2AQyAEy5RtcwlAD8DZgGl2nFhBBtADMtES1dRH0jJi9BUwUoUQoEKmRVFQ4bZCCAQ3RoAEkyLLBtABscmwYVKCgACgBKUTqeSogk8WQGklNk1NVaowtrWwdYRBQMfXljOqDkbQRRTQAaKGBtZYiEKJMm+tabDpSUbuJTHT08I2NVBRUVdG0yHl8S8rbRIveKqtI5hZLKA5MggMwABjWG1EILBpAAjGdTC1gJ8xCcujDQT1qrUni8iJkUKVfhAAGo5MpwaD-ABu8NEUkmsnwhDWtIATIyJjJpmzuMdUvsmbyXERzrjauwQnV1BBglB6SRiKQAER9FCq7r0GpS2rICDAODIThKgBU9XhUAAtNxugBqeqc4GODVdKAWrgDKUJCBlLjQHV6-WG42cPnAAB080WAFFimgIFw6hHI-4QMn6Q1IwgcmA6nUWEjmCw1kTkCS2hSqRA6vTWII1nWOS7gaCGg21lwGoIGg1vbV7oPdQajSa3sSPjZq9SAYsodou6ibP2VPdHs8uOUIJGytp+HVdeXKzY6pCoIiz5GAMzZjYAMVQlggdjqHO6AHoP1BVeCb+DVRUVcNxebdd33Q9amPKda0YHJRHBKAFDWODRCtBQGivAAWbMcigL8oD-LCgPSfEtzKHc9wPI9iknUlIKlRguHQSl2kItZSi4VBgFQZ5REYSw0PBc8QCExCEmQ3VaiYliKLQjjtC4ni+M8QSoAAVmEtZRI04SkKQhopPqP91OzTjuN4shIzBAjr2EkiHjIsCqIY6D6Mwv9b0jB8nxfN9P2-X9-0AwyMloisYLqVCLyQlCoGwNCDLqRElHw78UAWZAAEIVAI618oKwqisK0wAD9ytK3LvwAQWQfgJmKJwQjlKAAHJGAS9F+iQ1r2FdbQiByLguP4MgcmwCioCq9ZtCgMAcmQHIkCyJr1nAaB2uBQUUFShRWsjIA)

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer, it works perfect! I learned a lot about Typescript today.

Answer (score 0):

It actually seems to be possible, but you can't make nested objects. Try it out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwgJwJYGMDyAjAVhdYAHgGkIQBnKCAD2AgDsATKi4NBgcwG0BdAPigBeKAG9uAayioGUMpW4NE2FL14AuKEoQrkAXwDcAKCMAzOA0KoA9rJn1kYawBsAhvQAUp5NYSbtugA0UMDW-sooAJSaHmzuEOE6UcKCASjG5pbANnYMDk5u9KTkVLT0zKzsMjwCXj5+sIgoGDj4hMWU-MGhmvBIaFh4BMTyFPzRULHA8Ym6kSlaEcgZFla20nkoBfF1vpquDCDd1lD7h-OiRlBQyBDAcMiyUzOLScgTByALl9fX6LZsDb5FzxABqrmccGgIg8ADcAIxnI5QWEAJiRwQosyiSO+V1+11QpkmoEg1mJCOEQhEACI0sgaRd8QTrrd7o8UfCoAAqSZcgC0UAo8wA1JM0VBXFR6fNeRRjCyoHoIM4KNAfoqbncHrJWsMAHTeXwAUTyaAgFA8esI+okJTh8Mi+oQrjAHg8EnmQkEkmC9i2IPo4MhEAdkl4wThqMlVE+kXDmMivEikQVLL0zKVmbZOqBAcKEGDUN2CGOmOm9FT+IzGaM-wYFBcEH1zmsnA8+P9jkDoYADMFHR5e-qAMzzAD046gw5HRirdYBTZbbY7hM23YLHlErk0vb0wW3mnhekiQ-1ABYJ1PD9OLxn5-XG85m6325319tPKIKOgIQlp8ETgUKg2S2Joog0Eevb9lAIBQXu+5iD+f5HoB1jAaBDDgZBUAAKzQcEcF4dBegnmeuFXkhv7Pru+q4WhGE5NhmgjgRsEsSR97GEYk4UAAFtYcDOEw1AMKY1jIOg0DAHx0AUK4SBCuwcCEA80DicgUDYNYMmSsgnBNHkFBGF2n6hjex4HtgR5kY6BhAA). You have to change the type and function signature to that:

```
type NumericObject<Keys extends string[]> = {[k in Keys[number]]: number};

function interpolate(from: number, to: number): (state: number) => number;
function interpolate<Keys extends string[]>(from: NumericObject<Keys>, to: NumericObject<Keys>): (state: number) => number;
function interpolate(from: any, to : any) {
    // other code
}
```

You need to use a function here, because of signature overloading.

---

EDIT: My original answer didn't work, so I took a comment and modified it a bit. Try it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwgJwJYGMDyAjAVhdYKAXigDtFsUoAfKAbygG0BrKVMqAZ2DTIHMAugC5ylanXhI0WPASIBfANwAoUJCgAVAPZScuADyaAfCS1QIAD2AQyAEy5RtcwlAD8DZgGl2nFhBBtADMtES1dRH0jJi9BUwUoUQoEKmRVFXRtMh5fG2QwbQAbAEMbMyMLa1sHWEQUDH15YwAKIORtBFFNABooYG0uiIQokwBKElNmnlKIJPFkUcG9PCNTYlN6FSgoTOyiDjyCkpsANWLCuGhSZoA3AEZRKXrZfEJem4AmR7qZRrfuOYpFCLWrSBouIjrBhbbbsELNdQQYJQe4kYikABEyVSGPGm1hsOQEGAcGQnFRACooM07lAALTccYAampnygxUc2OBUCpXFUBISEEKXGg+IJUCJJLJUD+wAAdG0OgBRMi8VAQLjNWVy-wgTX3UZyhDFMDNZoscZQ1i9A4oI4zM4XCC3O6sQS9W4fdmOYpkECjN29LijQSjUb82EKGFR7aS0mcW35IoO86XVrtBC9fpB4AzcYc8LLQwmVRRjJZLhFCBywrafjNGGJ+02ZoABl6d1GbblAGZxgB6ftQVu9lThlTl7JVmt1hvbJvJlv0YqiVsKXrL0R3BRdkcAFgHQ83w7le6j48nlcK1dr9cbqrti+d9C46HOs2HvQKXFQwFQWVEehLC3Vt2ygEAQLXdcGFfd8ty-bQfz-ACGGAqAAFZQN6CCMNAhQd27dDDxgt9r1XOV0IQpD-zIQC0J7LDwNEBioLHdJBy4AALbQ4EKOwLDIIJtGQdBoGATjoC4YokG4Xg4EIUloCE5AoGwbRxPZZB+DqVUuBUBdjmfFcoG3DdsC3AjOyUIA). It basically remaps all the properties to make a new type:

```
type NumericObject = number | { [k in string]: number | NumericObject };
type ToNumObj<T> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: ToNumObj<T[K]> } : number;

const interpolate = <T extends NumericObject>(from: T, to: ToNumObj<T>) => (state: number): ToNumObj<T> => {
  // code
}
```

Comment: It still does not enforce that the two arguments have the same keys (line 31 in your playground link)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see that. Look at the edit